# Python Regex : find zip from html content

Tags: python, regex

i have a email template which is having email context in html formate,

now i wanted to find the zip number from the email html content,

for that i have used regex to search the zip code,
the content is like
**Formate 1:**

```
helllo this is the mail  which will converted in the lead &#13;
and here is some addresss  which will not be used..
&#13;
and the 
zip: 364001
city: New york
```

**formate 2:**

```
<p><b>Name</b></p><br/>
fname
<p><b>Last Name</b></p><br/>
lname
<p><b>PLZ</b></p><br/>
71392
<p><b>mail</b></p><br/>
heliconia72@mail.com
```

the code looks like,

```
regex = r'(?P<zip>Zip:\s*\d\d\d\d\d\d)'
zip_match = re.search(regex, mail_content) # find zip
zip_match.groups()[0]
```

this is searching for fomate 2 only, how can i write a regex so it work for both the formate.

Comment: A general advice would be to not try to parse HTML with regex, rather use a library like BeautifulSoup, extract text nodes only (discarding script, css) and use regex on them instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but, you can see the format 1 has no html code block, while format 2 does.

Comment: Why do you use a named group for the search but not with the group method? Also, if you look for 6 digits do `\d{6}`.

Comment: @LarsVegas it can be part phone number

Comment: See first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use regex for this (I would probably use `BeautifulSoup` for the second), you could use this for example:

```
regex = r'(?:zip:\s*|PLZ</b></p><br/>\n)(\d{5})'
zip_match = re.search(regex1, mail_content)
zip_match.groups()[0]
```

Comment: i recommend strip tags